# please help me, how to tie input and button through js in LWC, need to implement a contact filter by contact name

Tags: lightning-web-components, html, js

HTML:

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
        <div class="slds-m-bottom_small">
            <lightning-input
                type="text"
                label="SEARCH"
                value={keyword}
                placeholder="Search by name"
                onchange={searchKeyword}
            ></lightning-input>
        </div>
        <div style ="padding-bottom:10px ;">
            <lightning-button   
             label="FILTER"
             value={keyword}
             onclick={handleSearchKeyword}
            variant="brand">
        </lightning-button>
        </div>
        <lightning-datatable
         data={rows}
         columns={columns}
          key-field="Id">
         </lightning-datatable>
    </div>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from "lwc";
import getContactList from "@salesforce/apex/ContactController.getContactList";

const CONTACT_COLUMNS = [
    {
        label: "FIRST NAME",
        fieldName: "FirstName",
        hideDefaultActions: true,
        type: "text"
    },
    {
        label: "LAST NAME",
        fieldName: "LastName"
    },
    {
        label: "EMAIL",
        fieldName: "Email",
        type: "email"
    },
    {
        label: "ACCOUNT NAME",
        fieldName: "AccountUrl",
        type: "url",
        typeAttributes: {
            label: { fieldName: 'AccountName'}
        }
                 
    
    },
    
    {
        label: "MOBILE PHONE",
        fieldName: "Phone",
        type: "phone"
    },
    {
        label: "CREATED DATE",
        fieldName: "CreatedDate",
        type: "date",
        typeAttributes: {
            
            value:"1547250828000",
            year:"numeric",
            month:"numeric",
            day:"numeric",
            hour:"2-digit",
            minute:"2-digit",
            hour12:"true"
        }
    }
];

export default class ContactTable extends LightningElement {
    columns = CONTACT_COLUMNS;
    keyword = "";

    @track rows;
    
    searchKeyword(event) {
        this.keyword = event.target.value;
    }
      
    handleSearchKeyword(event){
        this.keyword = this.template.querySelector('lightning-input').value;

    getContactList({ searchKey: "$keyword" })
    
        if (result.data) {
            let AccountUrl;
            let AccountName;
            this.rows = result.data.map(row=>{
                AccountName= row.Account.Name;
                AccountUrl = `/${row.AccountId}`;
                
                return{...row,AccountName, AccountUrl}
                
            });
        } else if (result.error) {
            this.rows = undefined;
        }
    }

}

Apex:

    public with sharing class ContactController {
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static List<Contact> getContactList(String searchKey) {
        string searchKeyword = '%' + searchKey + '%';

        List<contact> contacts = [
            SELECT id, FirstName, LastName, Email, Account.Name, Phone, CreatedDate
            FROM Contact
            WHERE FirstName LIKE :searchKeyword
        ];
        if (contacts.isEmpty()) {
            throw new AuraHandledException('No Record Found...');
        }
        system.debug(contacts);
        return contacts;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are already assigning the value of lightning-input in keyword variable on change event.

```
    searchKeyword(event) {
        this.keyword = event.target.value;
    }
```

So no need to again fetch the value of lightning-input on button click just pass your keyword variable to your Apex controller method.

```
    handleSearchKeyword(event){
        this.keyword = this.template.querySelector('lightning-input').value;
        getContactList({ searchKey: this.keyword }).then(result => {
            if(result){
                let AccountUrl;
                let AccountName;
                this.rows = result.data.map(row=>{
                    AccountName= row.Account.Name;
                    AccountUrl = `/${row.AccountId}`;
        
                return{...row,AccountName, AccountUrl}
                }
            }).catch(error => {
                this.rows = undefined;
            });
    }
```

Let me know if this helps.

Regards,
Rohit Bhamdare

Comment: thanks, but I already knew that, I need it to work when the button is pressed

Comment: @ВладимирКарпов It should work when the button is pressed. If you're having problems, we might need more information. Do you get any errors? What debugging have you tried?